# Adding a form template to the index.html page - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

*** Java 1.8, Spring-Boot 1.4.0 ***

I have the following `Application.java` file in my project:

```
package tools;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    /* Use the User collections */
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
        return "index";
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param contact
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping("/contact")
    public String contactMessage(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
        // Store the contact info in the 'contact' collection.
        this.contactRepository.save(contact);
        return "thankyou";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The `Contact.java` model is simple:

```
package tools;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

/**
 *
 */
@Document(collection = "contacts")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String date;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2)
    private String message;

    // Define a public constructor
    public Contact() {}

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param message
     */
    public Contact(String name, String email, String message) {
        this.id = new ObjectId().toHexString();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        this.date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.message = message;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param message
     */
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }

}
```

In the `index.html` page I made sure to add the `contact` object in the form:

```
<form  action="#" th:action="@{/contact}" th:object="${contact}" method="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate="true">
   <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="true" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="true" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" th:field="*{message}" id="message" placeholder="Message" required="true" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="success"></div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Since the `contact` object is added to the `model` attribute, it shouldn't resulted in the following error:

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "index": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (index:684)
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (index:684)] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:401) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:328) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:294) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java:98) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
```

As far as I know, `Spring-Boot` already configures `@EnableWebMvc` that's why `index.html` is automatically displayed by `Spring-Boot` if placed in `"/static" (or "/public").`. I'm confused. How can I fix that?

Comment: in what folder is your index.html located ?

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte `/resources`